# Adding margins between elements cause element to start a new line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin

I created my own responsive web design grid with 12 columns (like bootstrap) and every row in this grid takes a 100% of the grid. In my html file I have three sections of which every section takes 33.33% of the page, 100% in total. When I try to add margins between those sections, the last section in line jumps to new line. I know that bootstrap uses offset classes to solve this issue, but I'm trying to implement a solution with my own responsive web design grid.

You can see the preview of the HTML and CSS code on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woyjhf4q/), or right here if you just want to see the code.

```css
 /********** Base Style **********/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

section {
    background-color: #999999;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    color: black;
    padding: 30px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#title1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: #D99A95;
}

#title2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: #C44346;
}

#title3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: #E2D496;
}

/* Simple Responsive Framework. */

.row {
    width: 100%;
}


/************** Large Devices Only **************/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/************** Medium Devices Only **************/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .col-md-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-md-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-md-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-md-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-md-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-md-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-md-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-md-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/************** Mobile Devices Only **************/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .col-xs-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-xs-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-xs-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-xs-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-xs-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-xs-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-xs-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-xs-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-xs-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-xs-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-xs-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-xs-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Module 2 Solution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Raleway|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Module 2 Solution</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h2 id="title1">Chicken</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </section>
        <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h2 id="title2">Beef</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </section>
        <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2 id="title3">Sushi</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to remove the margin from the column width, like in below sample, a portion of your code, using `calc()`

The `- 20px` in `width: calc(33.33% - 20px);` comes from your margin of 10px, 10 on each side of the `section`

```css
/********** Base Style **********/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

section {
    background-color: #999999;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    color: black;
    padding: 30px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#title1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: #D99A95;
}

#title2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: #C44346;
}

#title3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: #E2D496;
}

/* Simple Responsive Framework. */

.row {
    width: 90%;
}


/************** Large Devices Only **************/

    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Module 2 Solution</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h2 id="title1">Chicken</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </section>
        <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <h2 id="title2">Beef</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </section>
        <section class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <h2 id="title3">Sushi</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can simply add another div class inside the section and then set the margins for that class. The new div will take as much space his container allows, and you can set the margins on that new div. The outer div just controls responsiveness and contains the section div.

```
<body>
    <h1>Module 2 Solution</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="section">
                <h2 id="title1">Chicken</h2>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

---

```
.section {
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```